# How to get property from object returned by a custom templatetag filter without another filter

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I'm usign Django-CMS (v3.4.6), Django (v1.11), and Python (v2.7.x).

I have a custom templatetag filter called `get_foo` that takes an `my_obj`, does some processing and then returns an instance known to have property `bar`, however when I attempt to do the following, I get an `TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse some characters: my_obj|get_foo|.bar` error: `{% my_obj|get_foo.bar %}`

The only workaround I've found is creating another filter which returns `bar` and so the line in my template looks like this: `{% my_obj|get_foo|get_bar %}`. But I want to be sure: isn't there a way to do this without creating yet another filter?

Comment: Usually the idea is not to do a lot of processing in the template. I think it is better to do the processing in the view, and thus pass the "end product" to the template for rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `with` tag:

```
{% with my_obj|get_foo as my_foo %}
    {{ my_foo.bar }}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: That's precisely what I was looking for, thanks! I had tried something similar to that, but it looks like I had the syntax wrong.